# paypal adaptive payments guest implicit payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

**Hello,**

When calling Adaptive payments PAT API call i Would like to supply a credit card (or vaulted credit card) in an adaptive payment **without redirecting the guest account to paypal** - since our user has already supplied to us his credit card prior

I have been looking into the documentation and this doesn't seem supported - why? and is this planned to be changed anytime soon because this might make us reconsider PAYPAL as a provider  (in payments pay API call you are allowed to supply CC)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Payments APIs only support payments with PayPal Accounts. they do not support direct credit card payments. Also, Vault is only compatible with the new REST APIs - with saved credit cards in Vault, you can only use the new REST payment API to process the payment. here is the how to guide for that: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But in Adaptive payments you do enable guest payments - with redirecting the account. is there any reason not to allow an implicit behavior?
and whom should i request this feature from?

Comment: Guest payments is slightly different from direct credit card payments. From a card compliance policies perspective, a guest user is a paypal user. We establish relationship with them in most cases and there are certain limits on how many times some one can pay as a guest using the same credit card. Again all due to the card compliance policies.

Comment: Direct credit card processing on the other hand is different in nature that it's your customer not PayPal's customer that you are charging. So you are taking in the liability for collecting and managing the card data, and going to be vetted for processing credit cards.

Comment: apparently this is not true any more. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/ap-guest-payments/ "With the introduction of Guest Payments feature in Adaptive Payments web flow, users can now complete a payment by simply using a credit card."

Answer (score 0):

The REST API only supports transactions from a stored credit card in Vault to a business PayPal account,

What we need is P2P, we need a way to perform transaction between a sender (a stored credit card in a Vault) to receivers (other PayPal accounts),

Just like what the Adaptive Payments API,

Is there a way to achieve that? if not are there any workarounds?

Thanks.